# how do I make this element move backwards?

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do I stop the following interval and make the alien move backwards when it reaches 700px? I know I can do this with CSS but I want to do this strictly with JS. I don't understand how to stop the interval once it reaches the 700px left...

```js
var game = document.querySelector(".game");
var character = document.createElement("div");
character.setAttribute("class", "character");
game.appendChild(character);
character.style.height = 20 + "px";
character.style.width = 20 + "px";
character.style.background = "gold";


var alien = document.createElement("div");
alien.setAttribute("class", "alien");
game.appendChild(alien);
alien.style.height = 20 + "px";
alien.style.width = 20 + "px";
alien.style.background = "red";
alien.style.position = "absolute";

function flow() {
  var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(alien).getPropertyValue("left"));
  alien.style.left = left + 2 + "px";
}
interval = setInterval(flow, 10);

function stop() {
  var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(alien).getPropertyValue("left"));
  if (left > 700) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    alien.style.left = left - 10 + "px";
  }
};
setInterval(stop, 10);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.game {
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.character {
  position: absolute;
  top: 490px;
  left: 440px;
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
</div>
```

Any help?

Comment: Your program seems to work. When the cube reaches 700px, it stops moving. You can see it here working. 
https://jsfiddle.net/JSman225/afrxcue2/

Comment: and how do i make it flow backwards?

Comment: Use an integer that is set to either -1 och 1 and multiply that with your movement calculation. You shouldn't animate using setInterval because it creates a flimmering animation. Use requestAnimationFrame instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I think that @Justinas answer is best. It shows how to make your alien go backward Chikenlegpiece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce a `speed` variable which will switch from 2 to -2 when it reaches the right limit. You should then do the same at the left side, and switch the speed from -2 to 2 again.

As you want to keep moving, the `stop` function is no longer needed.

```js
var game = document.querySelector(".game");
var character = document.createElement("div");
character.setAttribute("class", "character");
game.appendChild(character);
character.style.height = 20 + "px";
character.style.width = 20 + "px";
character.style.background = "gold";

var alien = document.createElement("div");
alien.setAttribute("class", "alien");
game.appendChild(alien);
alien.style.height = 20 + "px";
alien.style.width = 20 + "px";
alien.style.background = "red";
alien.style.position = "absolute";

let speed = 2;

function flow() {
  var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(alien).getPropertyValue("left"));
  if (left > 700) speed = -2;
  else if (left <= 0) speed = 2;
  alien.style.left = left + speed + "px";
}
interval = setInterval(flow, 10);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.game {
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.character {
  position: absolute;
  top: 490px;
  left: 440px;
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To move your element you use `left + 2` so it always is moving to one direction.

So when reaching 700px mark you should reverse it to be `left - 2` until it's 0.

I have modified your code adding `currentDirection` variable

```js
var game = document.querySelector(".game");
var character = document.createElement("div");
character.setAttribute("class", "character");
game.appendChild(character);


var alien = document.createElement("div");
alien.setAttribute("class", "alien");
game.appendChild(alien);

var currentDirection = 1;
var hasMoved = false;

function flow() {
  var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(alien).getPropertyValue("left"));
  alien.style.left = (left + 2 * currentDirection) + "px";
}
interval = setInterval(flow, 10);

function stop() {
  var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(alien).getPropertyValue("left"));

  if (left > 700) {
    currentDirection = -1;
  } else if (left < 0) {
     currentDirection = 1;
  }
};
setInterval(stop, 10);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.game {
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.character {
  position: absolute;
  top: 490px;
  left: 440px;
  background: gold;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.alien {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
</div>
```